# KineticJS (4.4.3) achieve swiping between multiple pages (layers)

Tags: html, kineticjs, swipe, layer

I'm trying to develop an app with multiple pages (layers with additional items) and a swipe-functionality to switch between them. I've tried several variants, but somehow none of them could satisfy my needs, which are:

- scalability (draw everything in a fixed aspect ratio and scale it up/down to fit the browser window/screen)
- bring the visible layer to the center of the screen
- hide all other layers but the active/centered one
- swipe between the different layers (like iOS or Android-Homescreen)

This little image should get you a sneak peek into my chaotic mind: ;)

[image]

The blue rectangle is the currently active layer, it should fill up the screen as good as possible and it should be centered in the browser window. To access the hidden layers (red ones) the user has to swipe to the left/right.

All of this should be realized with the newest version of KineticJS, so if you have any suggestions how to realize this application please share them with me.

best regards

Comment: What problems do you have? You can use http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ for swipe event. layer.hide() for every layer except current.

Comment: I am simply looking for a better way to realize this. Currently I've made it with KineticJS (Kinetic.stage is the blue rectangle, the red ones are Kinetic.layers), it kinda works also on my desktop-pc with google chrome, but on mobile devices it is unusable, because of serious lag issues.

Comment: Try to create jsfiddle example. It will be better to help you.

Comment: @Lavrton here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6jnf/), it worked on my local server but somehow I don't get a result on jsFiddle. I hope it is enough for you, if not, please let me know. Another question: Is it possible to make the whole stage draggable but keep one Kinetic.Group in the same static position?